# Customize JSON Result on a Ruby on Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I'm using a ruby on rails backend for a application I'm working on.

I use `ActiveModel::Serializer` to handle the JSON results of my API:

```
format.json { render json: data, status: status }
```

In some cases I only want to give the user a possibility to query for specific attributes.

So e.g a profile has a rank in a highscore which takes "quite long" to be calculated. So if the user passes in an attribute with: `requestedAttributes: [:highscore, :messages]` I want to return the highscore and the messages in my rendered JSON response. This attributes can change, so writing a Serializer for each listing is not an option!

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an `option hash` to `as_json` in order to specify the desired attributes.

check here [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

Comment: As I said, I use ActiveModel::Serializer (see https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) because I want to be able to use the same JSON format at multiple places in my application. Do you know how this can be done there?